# error MSB3326: Cannot import the following key file XXXXXXSigningKey.snk

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, pfx, snk

While Building solution on TeamCity Server I am getting below error

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB3326: Cannot import the following key file: XXXXXXSigningKey.snk. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate store. [E:\BuildAgent\work\2ae7096f1a3f5702\dev\dir\proj.csproj]
[17:20:02]  [Step 3/9]   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2718,5): error MSB3321: Importing key file "XXXXX_XXXX_certificate.pfx" was canceled.

The error is for Key file and i don't have particular certificate for the error  XXXXXXSigningKey.snk. This certificate is intended to be used only while building the solution local dev environment.

I have already installed the certificate pfx file for "XXXXX_XXXX_certificate.pfx" certificate related error.

Comment: Same problem. Any fix found ?